# Allow only additions and hide existing records in access form

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a form in Access that is linked with a table. When a user opens the form, I do not want the user to access or view the existing records and only be able to submit a new entry.

I have already given the following values for AllowAdditions, AllowDeletions and AllowEdits as shown in the image below but this gives a button to navigate through all the records in the table.

- AllowAdditions - Yes
- AllowDeletions - No
- AllowEdits - No

[image]

Comment: Change "Data Entry" property to Yes.

Comment: Don't use a datasheet; instead create a form to accept the values of the various columns and save the new row.

Comment: In addition to HansUp's suggestion, you can try setting RecordSource to something like "select * from tblHours1 where false"   User can then submit new record(s) without viewing any existing (though they will be able to see any records they enter in that session)

Comment: Another suggestion is to open the form on `DoCmd.OpenForm "Form_Name", acNormal, , "1 = 0", , acDialog`. Then remove the record navigator from the base of the form in the properties.,